# Large Json Parser using Jackson Outof memory error

Tags: android, json, jackson

Am using Jackson parser for parsing large json response from service. It contains 1lakh records. When I have tested in TAB it's working fine. But when I have tested on Phone, It throw me out of memory error.

I have given largeheap="true" in android manifest file and increate MAX size 900 in eclipse ini file.

```
                System.out.println("init");

                jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(new                        InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));//EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8));

                System.out.println("jp" +jp.getCurrentName());

                mgdatas = objectMapper.readValue(jp, Gdatas.class);

            System.out.println("mgdatas");

            gdatas = mgdatas.get("GDATA");
            System.out.println("done successfully");
```

This is the sample code
If anyone knows kindly help me to resolve this error please.

Thank you